# Query for all Custom Apex Web Services "@RestResource"

Tags: apex, soql, rest

I am looking for a way to query for all Custom Apex Classes that have a `@RestResource` annotation.

I am currently using the following SOQL query and filtering for anything that has `@RestResource`.

```
select id, Body  from ApexClass
```

My only concern is that for a managed package, we will not be able to see the code inside the backage and obviously will not be able to filter for this.

Is there an alternative method for listing out all `@RestResources`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method for looking at managed, hidden code (unless they publish it elsewhere).

Regardless, the proper tool for the job is **`SOSL`**, not **`SOQL`**, as the former can search the text of the class body. If memory serves, the correct search would be:

```
FIND 'RestResource' RETURNING ApexClass (Name)
```